# how to use ssh command to connect to multiple computers and send different commands to each computers at same time

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I need to connect multiple computers to run different programs. For different computers, I need to send them different command. How to use ssh command to connect to multiple computers and send different commands to each computers? My command to run program for each computer is
`nohup Rscript program_i.R > program_i_out.txt`. To be detailed. I want to use 3 computers to run 3 programs. Then, I will send

`nohup Rscript program_1.R > program_1_out.txt` to first computer,

`nohup Rscript program_2.R > program_2_out.txt` to second computer,

`nohup Rscript program_3.R > program_3_out.txt` to third computer.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. You might like to provide a little more detail, with examples. What different (sorts of) commands do you need to send? How can you differentiate which command needs to be run on which computer?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637819/how-to-send-different-commands-to-multiple-hosts-to-run-programs-in-linux, which I think is the same question phrased slightly differently

Comment: There are ssh clients for this: look at mssh, mussh, clusterssh (some of these are gui).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ssh -f user@host '<your command here>'`.

From the ssh man page:

`-f      Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.
             This is useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or
             passphrases, but the user wants it in the background.`

For example, if i do `ssh -f <my computer> 'echo "hello $(pstree -p | grep sshd | wc -l) person in ssh!"`, it prints `hello 1 person in ssh!`.

After it prints 2 the session automatically exits, but you do not have to wait for it to exit. If I do `ssh -f <my computer> 'sleep 30 && echo "hello $(pstree -p | grep sshd | wc -l) person in ssh!"'` it appears as if nothing has happened and I can do anything as normal, but 30 seconds later, it prints `hello 1 person in ssh!`.

Using the `>` redirect will redirect all stdout to a file, but all errors will still be printed to your screen. To avoid this, you can use `&>` to redirect all output, stdout and stderr, to a file.

Comment: I use command `ssh -f mike@mycompter_1.com 'cd/home/temp && nohup Rscript L_6.R> L_6_sh.txt &' `. But it does not work: after I enter this command, it ask me to type password. And then it appear `[1] 948`, and it stuck there.  I only can use ctrl+c to get out,

Comment: @MikeBrown Try it without the ampersand at the end. If that doesn't work, try it without the `nohup`.

Comment: It works now! But I have a lot of programs to assign to different computers. After typing what you suggest, it always let type password (can you help me here?), and can you help make the command as sh file (I want to assign different commands to different computers at same time). Then, each time, I only need to edit that sh file and run it. I am a new user of Linux.

Comment: @MikeBrown Try this: `ssh -f mike@mycompter_$1.com 'cd/home/temp && nohup Rscript L_'$1'.R> L_'$1'_sh.txt &'`. Put it in a file, make the file executable (`chmod +x filename`), then each time you run it, pass in the number of the computer, ex, `./commandfile 2` will execute it on machine 2, and so on.

Comment: @MikeBrown `chmod +x filename` marks `filename` as an executable file. After you do this, you can execute the file from anywhere by just typing `/path/to/filename` at the terminal, or if you're in the same directory as filename, you can use `./filename`. Look at [this](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) page for more details on this.

Comment: It works! It is amazing! I put `ssh -f mike@c15-0330-01.com 'cd/home/temp && nohup Rscript L_1.R> L_1_sh.txt &'` in file `test.sh`. Then, it works. But I do not totally understand how to run multiple program at same time. My computer looks like c15-0330-01.com,c15-0330-02.com,... And for some reason, my programs is not sequential (names are totally different).

Comment: To avoid password requests, you need to create a public/private key, and add the public key to the remote machines.

Answer (score 0):

SSH can be invoked in a few ways. The most common way people invoke it is to use:

```
ssh user@host
```

This opens an interactive terminal. However, SSH behind the scenes actually has a calling style more like this:

```
ssh user@host /usr/bin/foo
```

So the first type basically just connecting and running bash for you, it's a convenience. It's basically doing this for you:

```
ssh user@host sh
```

Where `sh` is the shell for that system, which is probably `bash`.

For the sake of argument let's assume your command you need to run is `mycommand`.

(The reason I am simplifying this is because the command you gave as an example contains `nohup` and output redirection, meaning you need to properly escape the command. Also, if you're using `nohup` in an effort to make the command stay alive after the SSH connection terminates, you probably want to use `setsid` to make it a session leader. In either case you're going to also make it an asynchronous command using `&`)

> For different computers, I need to send them different command.

You didn't specify how you want to do this. For example, is the machine *initiating* the SSH connection the one that decides which command is ran, or is it specified by a configuration on the remote machine?

If your machine initiating the connections to various remote machines is the one that should decide which command is written, you need to store that information somewhere and use it.

One way you can do this would be to pipe data into SSH, since by default it will invoke `bash`, which will read from standard input:

```
cat command.txt | ssh user@host
```

I've used `cat comand.txt` as an example here that generates which command should be sent to SSH, because I have no idea how you are saving that information right now. It may be easiest to store all the information in a text file like this:

```
user  host  command
user2 host2 command2
user3 host3 command3
```

You could now create a pipeline that does it, although it will be somewhat complicated (you'll have to use a parser like `sed` or `awk`). It may be easier to use a light scripting language like Perl or PHP:

```
<?php

foreach (file('myfile.txt') as $line) {
    list($user, $host, $command) = explode(' ', $line);
    passthru("ssh $user@$host $command");
}
```